# xlsxwriter - Why shorter strings occupy the same size as twice larger strings?

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I'm writing data into xlsx with [xlsxwriter](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter). There are columns `business_unit`, `creator_login_sap`, etc. Total records in xlsx 130 000. `business_unit` and `creator_login_sap` are strings. `business_unit` has constant length of 4 chars. `creator_login_sap` has average length of 10 chars.

```
import xlsxwriter
import io

output = io.BytesIO()
wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output)
ws = wb.add_worksheet()

columns = ['business_unit', 'creator_login_sap', ...]
data = [('BU01', 'ALNUDOVAN00'), ...]

for col_idx, column in enumerate(columns):
    ws.write(0, col_idx, column)

for row_idx, row in enumerate(data, 1):
    for col_idx, value in enumerate(row):
        ws.write(row_idx, col_idx, value)
```

When I was trying to reduce file size I noticed that `business_unit` and `creator_login_sap` column weighs almost equal (~450 Kb). This fact confused me.

Why this happens? Maybe there is a way when shorter strings occupy less memory?

Comment: An `xlsx` file is a ZIP package containing XML files. The data is already compressed. You're storing 130K rows in a 450KB file, which means less than 4 bytes per row.  How much smaller do you want this to get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data is already compressed. `xlsx` is a ZIP package containing XML files. 130K rows in 450KB is less than 4 bytes per row. A text file with the same data would be 1.8MB. That's an impressive compression to 25% of the original size.

That said, it may be possible to reduce size even farther. You can test this by opening the file in Excel and saving it to a different file. If the result is smaller, there's room for improvement. Excel, the application, uses shared strings extensively to ensure the file is as small as possible. Instead of storing possibly repetitive strings in cells, it stores them in a Shared String resource and stores a reference to the shared value in the cell itself.

`xlsxwriter` already use Shared Strings to reduce the size. Other libraries don't do that, resulting in bigger files.

If you want to reduce the amount of RAM used at the expense of compression size, you can use the the `constant_memory` mode. This is explained in [Working with Memory and Performance](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_memory.html). This mode uses less memory by flushing each row and *not* using shared strings.  Another restriction is that it doesn't allow you to modify data after it's written though, which results in formatting restrictions.

```
wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output,{'constant_memory': True})
...
```

From the docs:

> The trade-off when using 'constant_memory' mode is that you won’t be able to take advantage of any new features that manipulate cell data after it is written. Currently the add_table() method doesn’t work in this mode and merge_range() and set_row() only work for the current row.

**Please don't "optimize" without reason**

I'm currently dealing with files containing 2K rows and 1M empty cells. Somehow, somewhere, someone tried to "optimize" something or other and ended up producing a 5MB file that Pandas has to process fully even though there's almost no data. Resaving such a 10MB file with Excel produces a 50KB file.

So think of the consumers of that file before rushing to "optimize" anything

Comment: Just to be clear: XlsxWriter uses shared strings by default. It only uses "Inline" strings instead of "Shared" strings when `constant_memory` mode is enabled. Also, an uncompressed XlsxWriter file will be the same size as an uncompressed Excel file. After compression the file size is generally the same as Excel but not exactly the same since Excel and XlsxWriter are using different zip libraries. The XlsxWriter file should still be comparable to an Excel file in size though.